# What does equilibrium return on 90-day Treasury Bills mean?

Tags: portfolio-management, yield-curve, risk-free

I have been reading NZ Superfund's 2015 Ref Portfolio Review ([here](https://www.nzsuperfund.co.nz/sites/default/files/documents-sys/2015%20Reference%20Portfolio%20Review.pdf)) and came across this notion:

> Our estimate of the equilibrium return on 90-day Treasury Bills is 5%.

And this is under the column Risk-Free Rate.
Can anybody expalin what does this mean?

Comment: I think they just mean their estimate of what the TBill rate will be in the long term. They think it will move from the current value to 5% over the coming years. It is their forecast or their opinion, nothing more.

Comment: Do you mean 90-day T-Bill will be at 5% in the long run? Or is it the rate on risk-free long-term rate (15-20Y risk-free rate)?

Comment: The former: the short term rate.

Comment: Isn't it little questionable to expect positive 5% return on short term T-Bill when there are negative rates all over the place?

Comment: Yes, it seems very high to me also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NZ has traditionally had rates higher than US.

As such, their very long run (or equilibrium) estimate of policy rates will likely be way above other developed markets.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just looked at historical rates since 1999 and yes, there were times when the short term rate did exceed 5%.